# Azure ML MSI deployment over ARM Templates enables purge protection on Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-machine-learning-service, infrastructure-as-code

I have discovered lately that when you deploy an `Azure ML` instance from the `ARM Template`, the `MSI` will override the purge protection settings of the `Key Vault`. It will enable purge protection on the `Key Vault`. This is not the behavior that I am looking for, because when trying to deploy it again, the template will fail saying that the `Key Vault` with the name already exists and you can't deleted before the retention period.

If you deploy the `Azure ML` instance manually and select the Key Vault, it will keep the disable purge settings. Any ideas how can we keep purge disabled hier?

The Azure ML properties that we used are mentioned bellow:

```
  {
    "type": "Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces",
    "apiVersion": "2020-09-01-preview",
    "name": "[variables('machineLearningWorkspaceName')]",
    "location": "[parameters('location')]",
    "identity": {
      "type": "[parameters('amlManagedIdentityOption')]"
    },
    "dependsOn": [
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', variables('applicationInsightsName'))]",
      "[resourceId('Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries', variables('containerRegistryName'))]"
    ],
    "tags": "[parameters('resourceTags')]",
    "properties": {
      "friendlyName": "[variables('machineLearningWorkspaceName')]",
      "storageAccount": "[variables('storageAccount')]",
      "keyVault": "[variables('keyVault')]",
      "applicationInsights": "[variables('applicationInsights')]",
      "containerRegistry": "[ variables('containerRegistry')]",
      "adbWorkspace": "[variables('adbWorkSpace')]",
      "hbiWorkspace": "[parameters('confidential_data')]",
      "allowPublicAccessWhenBehindVnet": "[parameters('allowPublicAccessWhenBehindVnet')]"
    }
  }
```

On the Key Vault ARM we have the following properties:

```
         "properties": {
                 "enabledForDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForDeployment')]",
                 "enabledForTemplateDeployment": "[parameters('enabledForTemplateDeployment')]",
                 "enabledForVolumeEncryption": "[parameters('enableVaultForVolumeEncryption')]",
                 "softDeleteRetentionInDays": 7,
                 "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                 "copy": [
                     {
                         "name": "accessPolicies",
                         "count": "[length(parameters('userObjectId'))]",
                         "input": {
                             "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
                             "objectId": "[parameters('userObjectId')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].Id]",
                             "permissions": "[parameters('userObjectId')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].Permissions]"
                         }
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to look up or compare with the deployment template that worked from Azure portal? When I tried to deploy from Azure portal with a new keyvault purge settings were enabled by default. Have you have used an existing keyvault with purge settings turned off? Do you see similar behavior if you create a new keyvault from the portal too?

Comment: thanks for reaching out. From the portal, if you choose an existing Key Vault with purge protection disabled it will keep it disabled after finishing the deployment of Azure ML.

Comment: On the key vault arm, you should be able to set `enablePurgeProtection: false`.

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario 1 :**
Created a `Machine Learning` using **Azure portal** and the `KeyVault` is provisioned as dependent resources where the purge production is set to **enabled** by default.

**Scenario 2 :**
Created a `Test keyVault` service as a independent resource and could see the **purge production** is set to **disabled** and could see an option to *enable* the same

**Scenario 3 :**
Created again a `Machine language` via **portal** with the `Test keyVault` (Disabled purge production)after deploying *Machine language* the *keyVault*(disabled purge production) **purge production** is **enabled** automatically.

Found an open article [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/9984) Where the problem was basically that attaching a `Key Vault` to an Azure Machine Learning workspace, automatically activates Purge Protection on that `Key Vault`

Answer (score -1):

While deploying the ML via Manually/Templates in Azure it `enables` **soft delete and purge protection** in Key Vault by default. It protect keys against accidental or malicious deletion. we don’t change it into **Disable** because it is Design behavior.[Refer machine learning security baseline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/benchmark/azure/baselines/machine-learning-security-baseline#94-ensure-protection-of-backups-and-customer-managed-keys)

Once **Purge Production** is `enabled`, it cannot be disabled or overridden by anyone including Microsoft. [Refer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/key-vault-recovery?tabs=azure-powershell#what-are-soft-delete-and-purge-protection)

You need as an feature request make vote or submit a feedback  [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/906355-azure-key-vault/suggestions/37900363-allow-keyvault-purge-when-purge-protection-is-en)

Comment: Not completely true, from the portal if you deploy KV first and the Azure ML and choose the KV it will not enable purge by default. Also the argument we don't change it into Disable because it is design behavior is not very compeled.